# How should Selenium and Selenium 2 related questions be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tagging, selenium

At Stackexchange there are two tags for selenium and selenium2 to distinguish between both versions. I think this is important because they are very different from each other. On the other hand Selenium 1 will die some day and the tag could become inappropriate. What do you think?

### Update

According to the first answers, each part of Selenium should get its own tag:

selenium1
selenium2
selenium ide
selenium grid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't selenium1 and selenium2 be preferable to selenium and selenium2? As you say, one day selenium1 will be obsolete, and it'll become confusing for Selenium newbies looking for help, as they'll find a lot of obsolete stuff misleadingly tagged as just "selenium".

Better to enforce tags strictly now, so that they remain useful.

Comment: you are correct, that would be much better

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to keep following tags at the minimum -

Selenium1, Selenium2, Selenium IDE and Selenium Grid

Comment: I agree. Selenium is VERY different depending on which part you are talking about. You might want to even add Selenium Grid as well

Comment: Added Selenium Grid :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take for example the StackOverflow site - there are multiple tags for different versions of frameworks/toolkits/specifications/etc. and one tag that relates to the thing in general.

Imho, separate tags for versions should exist - they explicitly specify in a clear & straightforward way the problem domain and save time of both the author of the question & potential answers.

One example would be that I might have just started working with JPA 2.0 and became an expert in it for X weeks. I would be able to answer questions tagged "jpa2" but not "jpa1.0" since the framework changed significantly and i am not that familiar with 1.0 based on my 2.0 training.